# Error with minSdk version

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am trying to support Android 4.0 devices.
I keep getting following errors.

How do I fix them?

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseManifest'.
>
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library
>    [com.github.mark-dlc:RadioPlayerService:88b5de0] C:\Users\Emmanuel\Documents\Android Development\xspace\3\app\
>   build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.github.mark-dlc\RadioPlayerService\88b5de0\AndroidManifest.xml
>
> Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="co.mobiwise.library" to force usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RadioPlayerService` will not work in devices less than API 16

> minSdkVersion cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library com.github.mark-dlc:RadioPlayerService

Options:

1. Find a new library
2. Remove that library
3. Follow the suggestion in the message *"use `tools:overrideLibrary="co.mobiwise.library"` to force usage"*, and pray that it works (probably won't work, though)

Comment: Thanks this helped. God bless you

Answer (score -1):

Try by changing build.gradle file
`minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 14`

Hope it would help.